# Is it ok to add comments/answers to old questions?

Tags: discussion

Is it ok to revive old questions (e.g. last answer/comment older than 6 months) with new comments and/or answers?

Comment: If you have nothing of value to contribute, no. If you have, then **YES!**

Answer (score 9):

Yes.  There's even [a badge for it](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/17/necromancer)!